# Git bash and sqlcmd

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sqlcmd

I'm using a shell script in git bash to call sqlcmd to run some sql scripts. The script names are based on the git branch name, so the command is sqlcmd -E -S mySQLServer -d myDB "*$branch*sql"

It works fine from the command line, but I want to repeat it for several git branches, so I have a script that calls this script for a list of branches:

```
While read branch
do
  . C:/sqlScript.sh $branch
done < "$1"
```

The file with the list of branches is passed in $1

What happens is that is reads the first branch from the list, but never moves on to the next one. It repeatedly executes sqlScript.sh with the same value in $branch.

If I change sqlScript to just echo $1, everything works as expected. When I call sqlcmd, the first branch only is passed.
So why does sqlcmd mess things up ?

Comment: Just a side note: this has nothing to do with Git at this point, it's purely bash. "Git-bash" is simply a port of bash to Windows that's included in Git-for-Windows because Git requires a POSIX-style shell, and bash was there for free.

Comment: Is the uppercase `While` a typo, or is it uppercase in your script as well?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the leading dot, invoke `C:/sqlScript.sh ...` rather than `. C:/sqlScript.sh ...`

---

`. scripts.sh` is short for `source script.sh` ,: it will execute the commands listed in `script.sh` in the current shell. If you have a command such as `exit` it will exit the current shell.

A regular invocation will start a separate shell, which won't mess with your current one.

Comment: Thanks, but executing either way has the same result. It is specifically a problem when executing sqlcmd. The script can call git checkout and git pull and will work for each branch, but if the script calls sqlcmd, it gets stuck on the first branch

Comment: you will have to debug further : can you add `echo $branch` at the beginning of your loop, and `echo $1` at the top of your `sqlScript.sh` ?

Comment: If I put echo statements in the scripts, what I see just confirms that it's the call to sqlcmd that is the problem.  The call to sqlcmd appears to do some sort of reset that makes the calling script repeatedly read the first branch from the list. With sqlcmd being called, all the echo statements display the name of the first branch.